# LEFT JOIN Oracle DB лимит строк

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, join

Каким образом можно сократить количество взятых строк из таблицы `Jobs`, чтобы при выборе значений брались все значения из первой таблицы и только 10 значений из второй?

```
SELECT *
FROM HR.JOB_HISTORY 
LEFT JOIN HR.JOBS 
ON JOB_HISTORY.job_id = JOBS.job_id
WHERE rownum < 10;
```

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() в CTE и отбор по полученному значению в основном запросе.

Comment: @Akina Не совсем понял вас, как именно это можно использовать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236229/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-this-left-join-to-one

Comment: `cross apply` как вариант

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так:

```
select * 
from hr.job_history jh 
left join (
    select * 
    from hr.jobs jb
    order by job_id
    fetch first 10 rows only) jb on jb.job_id = jh.job_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM HR.JOB_HISTORY JH
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *, 
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JB.job_id 
                                      ORDER BY JB.id -- обязательна уникальная сортировка
                                      ) rownum 
            FROM HR.JOBS JB ) JBS
ON JH.job_id = JBS.job_id
WHERE JBS.rownum < 10;
```